# Mail not working when running task schedule in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I trying to send mail using a `cron` job.

I have a `department` table and an `activity` table. If I run command then the mail sending but the problem is I want each department will get their activity mail.

For example: I have `SD` dept. The `SD` dept will get their activity mail and other departments will not get this mail.

I am uploading my code here. Please suggest me how can I fix this problem. 
Thank in Advance.

```html
   public function sendNotificationForDepartment()
    {
        $departmentInfo = Department::pluck('department_name');

        foreach ($departmentInfo as $department_name) {
            $headMail = User::join('departments', 'departments.id', 'users.department_id')
                ->where('departments.department_name', '=', $department_name)
                ->where('users.is_head', 'Yes')
                ->orderBy('department_name')
                ->select('users.email')->get();



            $departmentPending = IssueCustomer::leftJoin('assets', 'assets.id', 'issue_customers.plate_no')
                ->join('departments', 'departments.id', 'issue_customers.department_id')
                ->where('departments.department_name', $department_name)
                ->where('issue_customers.issue_status', '!=', 'Done')
                ->where('issue_customers.organisation_id', 1)
//                    ->where('issue_customers.issue_status', '=', 'Pending')
//                    ->orwhere('issue_customers.issue_status', '=', 'Processing')

                ->select('issue_customers.id',
                    'departments.department_name',
                    'issue_customers.organisation_name',
                    'issue_customers.issue_symptom',
                    'issue_customers.remarks',
                    'assets.registration_no',
                    'issue_customers.issue_posted_at'
                )->get();



            if(count($departmentPending) > 0) {
                Mail::to($headMail)
                    ->queue(new CustomerIssuePendingMail($departmentPending));
            } else {
                $this->info('No pending status found');
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: have you run your task scheduler with terminal...?

Comment: yes.now I am testing on my localhost.

Comment: your code worked @kaziBablu ....?

Comment: yes, my code work but mail does not go to the individual department head. Head get every department activity. I want  SD department Head gets only Sd dept. activity, not other department activity.

Comment: instead of sending mail, print $headMail and check it from terminal

Comment: it's ok I get $headMail list it fine but my activity ex: SD Dept. activity does not go SD dept. head mail. that the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180648/discussion-between-kazibablu-and-shaielndra-gupta).